# What do these two figures of speech mean? Embrace the grind and lower your shoulder

Tags: meaning, idioms, american-english, figures-of-speech

I came across these two figures of speech:(a) Embrace the grind and (b) Lower your shoulder in one of the Instagram posts of Dwayne Johnson(The Rock)

[image]

Since I am not a native English speaker I just need to know what do these two terms mean?

Comment: It's an old idiom -- "Keep your nose to the grindstone, shoulder to the wheel".

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Keep+your+nose+to+the+grindstone%2C+shoulder+to+the+wheel%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

embrace the grind: embrace the effort, the tough fight

lower your shoulder: lower your stance (as when you want to go/pass through someone, as someone in a defensive line, as in American football), prepare to attack

Comment: "Lower your shoulder" refers to placing your shoulder lower against what you're pushing against, to allow you to exert more force.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Marius Hancu’s answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/238885/26083),
Johnson seems to be using this meaning of ***embrace:***

> to take or receive gladly or eagerly; accept willingly:
>   For example: *to embrace an idea.*
>                  [— Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/embrace)
>
> to accept (something or someone) readily or gladly
>   to take up especially readily or gladly <*embrace* a cause>
>         [— MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embrace)

The MW definition goes on to compare *embrace* to ***[adopt](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adopt),*** which

> implies accepting something created by another or foreign to one's nature 
>   <forced to *adopt* new policies>.

My interpretation is that *embrace* is being used (somewhat idiomatically)
in a way similar to *adopt* (as defined above)
and ***accept*** in the [Kübler-Ross model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCbler-Ross_model),
which categorizes people’s reaction to adversity
on a scale from denial to acceptance. 
I interpret Johnson’s post as meaning:
“Don’t deny or ignore your situation;
don’t waste your energy on anger; don’t wallow in depression. 
Accept the fact that you’re in the situation, and deal with it.”

[***Grind***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grind) is probably being used in these senses:

> (noun) boring or difficult work
>   dreary, monotonous, or difficult labor, study, or routine
>
> (verb) oppress, harass
>   to weaken or destroy gradually — usually used with *down* 
>   <poverty *ground* her spirit down>

---

Just for fun: I found a counterpoint in [To Embrace vs. To Accept](http://coachcampus.com/coach-portfolios/power-tools/moraima-ferradas-reyes-to-embrace-vs-to-accept).

Comment: "Embrace" is relatively easy to understand.  But how do you explain "grind"?

Comment: And here I thought "grind" was the one that was relatively easy to understand.  I've updated the answer.